# Included layout EditText it´s not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Let me explain that through words... 
I have two layout involved, where 1 layout is the the main layout and the other layout is included in the main layout.
I have a clickable EditText in the included layout (second layout), but when I put the code in the java of the second layout I can't click it.
Any idea on how to achieve this?
This is my code in my EditText

```
edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogBox.ponesone = cs_ponesone;
        edittext.setText(score);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogBox.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //finish();
    }
});
```

UPDATE: xml of edit text

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/ponehone"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextbox"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:clickable="false" 
                android:cursorVisible="false" 
                android:focusable="false" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="@string/ten" />
```

Comment: add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` into u r `EditText`

Comment: Make `android:clickable="true" ` not as `android:clickable="false" `.

Comment: lol let me check on it didnt see that one very clearly

Comment: @HakHak then it's not issue about code

Comment: but is it possible to put onclick event on the java file of the included layout and you are in the mainlayout?

Comment: then why you included this? directly add this into mainlayout

Comment: because there are other layout that i want to include and i will hide unhide those included layout depending on user selection.my problem is  the onclick isnt working so i have doubts if its possible or not

Comment: @HakHak u tested this into Emulator but test into real device? an let me know

Comment: @MD i havent tested it in real device but i will if i have time and i will get back on you will it be ok with you>?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47227/discussion-between-m-d-and-hak-hak)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ponehone"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbox"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:hint="@string/ten" />
```

Comment: i dont really get why it doesnt work it seems like it doesnt its there but its not when i tried your code a cursor should appear but it doesnt appear when u click it..maybe its not possible maybe the code should be in the main activity?what do you think?